# Deploy a Java Web Application on Red Hat Linux Server using GlassFish

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, glassfish

I have developed a JavaEE 7.0 Web Application using NetBeans (IDE) and GlassFish 4.1.0 (web server).

The application is working like a charm when I deploy it on the localhost. Now, I would like to deploy it on a Red Hat Linux Server using GlassFish. 
I am very little experienced regarding Linux Servers deployment. Therefore, I looked for some tutorials on the internet. I found a lot of them for Apache Tomcat deployment but none for GlassFish.

Do you have an idea of how to deploy a JavaEE 7.0 Web Application on a Red Hat Linux Server using GlassFish, please ?

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GlassFish offers an admin console GUI, which by default is available at https://example.com:4848

The GUI allows to upload, deploy and manage web applications.

See: [how to deploy war file to Glassfish?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197484/how-to-deploy-war-file-to-glassfish)